# How to improve get toast correct rate on Appium 1.6.3 with uiautomator2?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, python-appium

I tried to test getting toast message on android device with Appium 1.6.3, but it is disappointed for me,the rate to correct get toast is very low. Is there anyone help me?

Comment: My test devices platformVersion=6.0.1,API Level=23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Step 1:
public static BufferedImage getTOASTSnapShot(AppiumDriver appiumDriver, String event) {
            BufferedImage originalImage=null;
            BufferedImage resizedImage=null;
             {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Starting\n\n\n\n");
                     scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) appiumDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                     System.out.println("after scrfile\n\n\n\n");
                     originalImage = ImageIO.read(scrFile);
                     System.out.println("after originalFile\n\n\n");

                } catch (Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return originalImage;


    Step 2 :
    public BufferedImage clickfortoast(String element)
        {
            try{
            WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
            webElement.click();
        BufferedImage Toast=    Report.getTOASTSnapShot(appiumDriver, "Click: " );
            System.out.println("Click element: " +element);
            return Toast;
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

    Step 3 :
    BufferedImage bufferedImage=dummyPage.clickfortoastimage(PROFILE_PAGE_LOGIN_TO_WALLET_PAGE_SIGN_IN);
            String result1=dummyPage.togettext_out_of_toast(bufferedImage);
            String TOAST_MESSAGE_WRONG_CREDENTIALS= "  " ;
            String mes2=" Toast message to be checked for  to be checked";
            boolean check = StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result1,mes1);
                System.out.println(check);
                boolean check1=StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result1,mes2);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.It depends upon how dynamic data is coming.
2. If you want to get toast data while swiping than it becomes hard to get accurate data.

Comment: Displaying toast message after long press one button

Comment: Now can not get toast message almost

Comment: script as blew:  toast.press(title).wait(1000).release().perform()   driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@text,'message')]")

Comment: on click take a screenshot and in that use OCR method to get text and than search for the desired string in the text got from the OCR

Comment: Now appium1.6.3 has supported to identify toast message。

Comment: I want to solve this problem with new feature of appium 1.6.3

Comment: So there is any suggest of below my script to get toast message ? thanks

Comment: No if you want I can help you out with what I am doing .

Comment: Step 1:public static BufferedImage getTOASTSnapShot(AppiumDriver appiumDriver, String event) {
  BufferedImage originalImage=null;
  BufferedImage resizedImage=null;
   {
   try {
    System.out.println("Starting\n\n\n\n");
     scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) appiumDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     System.out.println("after scrfile\n\n\n\n");
     originalImage = ImageIO.read(scrFile);
     System.out.println("after originalFile\n\n\n");
   
   } catch (Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  return originalImage;

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample code snippet to verify toast message using appium uiautomator2 driver

```
assertNotNull(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
            By.xpath("//*[@text='Clicked popup menu item Search']"))));
```

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/72b9e6a70d3ebfba9bf6b74813e9644b2f2a9e08/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/UIAutomator2Test.java#L94